# Dependency checks skip not working in pacman when `pacman -Udd package.pkg.tar`

Tags: linux, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I have Arch Linux with package `babel-cli` installed (this package conflicts with package `openbabel`, which is **NOT** installed).

I write custom PKGBUILD:

```
pkgname=openbabel-fake
pkgver=9.99
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Fake package, that provides openbabel"
arch=('x86_64')
provides=(openbabel)
```

Then I run `makepkg` and get file `openbabel-fake-9.99-1-x86_64.pkg.tar`.

Then I try to install this package via `pacman -Udd openbabel-fake-9.99-1-x86_64.pkg.tar` and get error, that packages `openbabel-fake` and `babel-cli` conflicts. From `man pacman`:

```
    -d, --nodeps
       Skips dependency version checks.
       ...
       Specify this option twice to skip all dependency checks.
```

How can I install `openbabel-fake-9.99-1-x86_64.pkg.tar` without getting error about conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never processed that kind of strange manipulation but what I can say,

If you don't run `makepkg` without :

> -d, --nodeps     Skip all dependency checks

then the compiled package will always check dependency (in my opinion)

So if you do:

```
makepkg -d
```

then

```
pacman -U *.xz
```

should work.